# Docker - Problems with the vocabs

Tags: docker

I am currently starting to use Docker. I have some private servers and thought learning some new stuff might not hurt. I have some problems because I do not really understand what I really need.

My first issue that I am not really sure what part of Docker I am shipping to my client servers. I understand that an image is the basis for a container so that means I have to prepare an image which I then put on my servers in order to make a container out of it?
I read about the dockerfiles. From my understanding the dockerfiles are like a blueprint to create an image - is that correct? 
Last but not least: I need to add some configurations file to the docker containers - Is the best practice to use "Volumes" for that? Or is it better practice to put the files on the Docker host and then access them?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all correct what you say. a Dockerfile is the "blueprint" of each docker container you want to build.

- if your config is static it makes more sense to add it into your dockercontainer with your Dockerfile.
- if you want to change the config while your docker container is running, then mount it with volume.

if you have more then one docker container and they have to call each other, read some infomations about docker-compose. with docker-compose the docker container are still "stand alone" virtual machines but are able to see each others.

Comment: Ah great, docker compose was what I was looking for without knowing it! Thank you very much! One small question is left though: I've used images in the past which allowed me to run them with an argument specifing which configuration file to use: How is that made? Is that done through the entrypoint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @bqcqON i am glad that i could help you. to your Q im not sure but the docker run reference docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ says that you can pass arguments for the run command. maybe search  a bit there?